# Why is the null space of a transformation equals the span?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = I + xy^H $ where $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n $. My book says that it follows that if $A$ is singular then

$$ Null A = Span ( x ) $$

why is this the case?

Comment: Just by curiosity: what does $y^H$ means?

Comment: @Taladris Conjugate transpose (a.k.a. Hermitian transpose, hence the $H$). It's usually denoted by $y^\ast$ in linear algebra literature, but $y^H$ is more popular in numerical linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$$A = I + xy^H $$
$$Null(A) =\{z \big| z \in \mathbb {C}^n, Az = \theta_n\}$$
$$A z= z + xy^Hz $$
$$z + xy^Hz = \theta_n$$
$$xy^Hz = -z$$
Assume- $y^Hz\neq 0$, then-
$$x = \frac{-1}{y^Hz}z.$$
Otherwise, if $y^Hz = 0$, then- $Az=z \implies z=\theta_n$. So it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To find Null$A$, note that

$Az=0$ implies $z+xy^Hz=0$

i.e. $z=-xy^Hz$

or $z=x(y^Hz)$

$y^Hz$ being a scalar, we can say that $z$ is a multiple of $x$.
Hence follows the result.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that for any vector $z$ (of the correct size), $y^Hz$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, which is to say that it is a scalar (in fact, it's the dot product of $y$ and $z$.

Now, note that if $A$ is singular, there must be a non-zero vector $z$ such that
$$
Az= z+(y^Hz)x=0
$$
Note that $z$ must be a multiple of $x$ for the above to hold. Conversely, if it holds for one non-zero multiple of $x$, it holds for all of them.